# Submit FORM data then return response

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which sends post data to my form and alerts the expected result, however I'm finding it hard to save this as a variable I can use outside the function, can anyone offer any help?

```
<script>
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "form.php";
var params = "name=test";
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.(params);
</script>
```

Comment: What is the responseText ? Is it json ?

Comment: The HTML response from the webpage

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a variable and set it when the request responsed by server;

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "form.php";
var params = "name=test";
var response;
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
        response = http.responseText;
    }
}
http.(params);
```

Comment: alert(http) and alert(response) both return "undefinied". Am I missing something? Apologies, I'm relatively new to Javascript

Comment: Is it typo "http.(params);" -> http.send(params);

Comment: Even when I do that, doing alert(response) returns "undefined"